# When i pass text without space(tech) its not showing any error when i pass text with spaces(tech life) its showing error in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

When I pass text without space (tech) i'ts not showing any error, when I pass text with spaces (tech life) it's showing error in `thymeleaf`

```
<span th:if="${toTimestamp == null && fromTimestamp == null}">
   <a class="btn btn-link" th:with="search=${search}"
            th:href="@{/feed(page=1, sortDirection=${sortDirection == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'}, author=${checkedAuthors}, tag=${checkedTags},
     __(${#strings.isEmpty(search)} ? '' : ('search=' + ${search}))__)}">
 Sort by Published Date</a>
</span>
```

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Could not parse as expression: "@{/feed(page=1, sortDirection=${sortDirection == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'}, author=${checkedAuthors}, tag=${checkedTags},
                       __(${#strings.isEmpty(search)} ? '' : ('search=' + ${search}))__)}" (template: "blog/feed" - line 141, col 16)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: The error states that what you have in the `th:href` attribute cannot be parsed by Thymeleaf. It is not a valid Thymeleaf expression. It seems quite complex, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i dont want show null param in url